# Store multiple foreign key in one attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing rails api.
I am having trouble with saving an array of foreign keys in one column.
There are two models: Block and Employee. The employees has many blocks and blocks has_many employees. The many to many relationship.
This is block's index.

```
[{
  id:1,
  name: "Block A"
 },
 {
  id:2,
  name: "Block B"
 },
 {
  id:3,
  name: "Block C"
 }
]
```

This the body of employee's post request.

```
{
  "first_name":"John",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "email": "smith@gmail.com",
  "block_ids":'[1, 2, 3]'
}
```

When create an employer user must specify which blocks the employee controls. In block_ids column I want to store the foreign keys of above blocks.

1) Question: how to store many foreign keys using array in one model attribute.

So Smith controls the blocks which ids are equal to 1, 2 and 3.

2) Question: Then using rails controller how to know which blocks the users control. I mean how to know name of blocks through ids which will be specified in block_ids attribute.

Comment: What's your question?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn. I edited my question

Comment: Your employee can have many blocks and can one block belong to many employees? In Rails we don't store data like this, you will have to create custom methods to fetch data then.

Comment: @Deep. Yes one block can belong to many employees. I understand that this is a many to many relationship.

Comment: So why don't you use this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association or this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong approach. Don't store the foreign keys in an array. Make a join table instead.

In the simplest arrangement, use a [has-and-belongs-to-many relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association). This is for when you don't need to refer to the thing that connects the two models as a thing in its own right e.g. a car has many parts. If the connection is a real thing e.g. appointments connecting doctors and patients, then use a [has-many-through relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), where the join table has its own model.

The reason these approaches are better is that SQL will not be able to use proper JOINs to query across your data if you store the foreign keys in an array. Also, you are unable to specifically mark them as foreign keys, so the database will not be able to enforce [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) for you should you need this.